# Select option stay selected always

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using Wordpress Multisite with subdirectories like http://mymite.com/ and http://mymite.com/subsite/

I've got city selector

```
<select id="city-select" name="city_select">
<option>Choose</option>
<option  value="http://mymite.com/subsite/">
Subsite
</option>
<option value="http://mymite.com/subsitetwo/">
Subsite Two
</option>
```

And a jquery script which adds attribute `selected=selected` to the option if its value equal to `window.location`

```
jQuery('select#city-select>option').filter(function () {
var crurl = window.location;
if (jQuery(this).val() == crurl) {
    jQuery(this).attr('selected','selected');
}
});
```

This part works fine. The problem is when i start navigating in subsite(i.e. clicking on menu and following to the http://mymite.com/subsite/catalog/) Selected option became not selected.
How can i compare not the full link but the part of it with the value of option so it will be selected all the time when i'm surfing in that particular subsite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the URL starts with `http://mymite.com/subsite/` etc, and not just equals it:

```
jQuery('#city-select > option').filter(function () {
    return window.location.href.indexOf( this.value ) === 0;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Location] has no method 'indexOf' I'm using jquery ver=1.10.2

Comment: How i should use that?

Comment: @mandeep try it now - I added `href` as `window.location` is an object, not a string :)

Comment: Oops, didn't even notice, just copied if from the question, but the href property is needed to return a string in this case

Comment: @Archer i can't vote up but you Helped me so much! Thank you! It is working perfectly!